# Dynamic Linq & ICompare

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, sql-order-by

I'm trying to make use of James McCormack's guide to using a custom IComparer with Dynamic Linq.  - see http://zootfroot.blogspot.co.uk/2009/10/dynamic-linq-orderby.html?showComment=1347276236930#c11348033278810583

I use a query to pull back an Enumerable of string values:

```
.Select("fieldname").Distinct()
```

Then try to use

```
.OrderBy(item=>item.GetReflectedPropertyValue("fieldname"),new myComparer())
```

GetReflectedPropertyValue is a helper method defined by James as

```
public static string GetReflectedPropertyValue(this object subject, string field)
{
object reflectedValue = subject.GetType().GetProperty(field).GetValue(subject, null);
return reflectedValue != null ? reflectedValue.ToString() : "";
}
```

But get the error "'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'OrderBy' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicQueryable.OrderBy(System.Linq.IQueryable, string, params object[])' has some invalid arguments"

Any ideas? I'm new to this and just trying to get something working before I get the time to actually go through and learn it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's hard to tell based only on what you've posted because the resolution of `OrderBy` will depend on the implementation of `myConverter`.  But, Since `GetReflectedPropertyValue` returns `string`, `myConverter` must implement `IConverter<String>` to be used with `OrderBy`.  If it doesn't, and it implements something like `IComparer<MyItem>` then compiler is really looking for a method `OrderBy(this IEnumerable<object>, Func<object,string>, IComparer<MyItem>)` which doesn't exist and spits out that error.

If that isn't clear, provide the details of `myConverter` and I can be more specific.

If you're using something that doesn't implement `IComparer<T>`, then you can wrap the `IComparer` with something that implements `IComparable<string>` so that it is compatible with `Orderby`.  For example:

```
public class MyStringComparer : IComparer<String>
{
    readonly IComparer comparer = new MyComparer();
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        return comparer.Compare(x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I'm actually using this comparer http://www.davekoelle.com/files/AlphanumComparator.cs which I would think is ok as it's expecting a general object?

Comment: By the way, when I try your wrapper I get this message "The non-generic type 'System.Collections.IComparer' cannot be used with type arguments" - ignore this, realised I hadn't included System.Collections.Generic

Comment: Yeah talk about schoolboy error!  It works now. Thank you, really appreciate the help Peter.