# Error when use Dynamic Linq & ICompare

Tags: c#, linq, expandoobject

I read this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350965/dynamic-linq-icompare) and apply to my code.

```
//listSort contains ExpandoObjects
            List<dynamic> listSort = new List<dynamic>(listDynamic.Count);
            foreach (var item in listDynamic)
            {
                dynamic objDynamic = OrderBySpecialCharacter.ConvertToExpand(item);
                string sortValue = OrderBySpecialCharacter.GetValueInExpandoObject(objDynamic, colSortText);// "Name");
                objDynamic.Sort = OrderBySpecialCharacter.ConvertToACSII(sortValue.ToUpper());
                listSort.Add(objDynamic);
            }

            List<dynamic> sortedList = new List<dynamic>();
            if (colSort2 == null && colSort3 == null)
            {
                //Error in below line
                sortedList = listSort.OrderBy(x=> x.GetReflectedPropertyValue("Sort"),new MrFourCompare<string>()).ToList();
            }

    ----------------
     public static ExpandoObject ConvertToExpand<T>(T objInput)
            {
                ExpandoObject objExpand = new ExpandoObject();
                PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
                IDictionary<String, Object> iExpand = ((IDictionary<String, Object>)objExpand);
                foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
                    iExpand.Add(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(objInput));
                return (ExpandoObject)iExpand;
            }
    --------------------
```

And I see error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0411  The type arguments for method
>   'Enumerable.OrderBy(IEnumerable, Func, IComparer)' **cannot be inferred from the usage. Try
>   specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.** DemoDynamicObject   C:\Users\MrFour-IT\Desktop\DemoDynamicObject\DemoDynamicObject\OrderBySpecialCharacter.cs   154 Active

I don't know how to fix it! Please help me! Thanks

Comment: This is topic which i read
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350965/dynamic-linq-icompare

Answer (score 0):

If your have `IComparer` like this code:

```
public class MrFourCompare: IComparer<String>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        return string.Compare(x, y);
    }
}
```

according your referred link you most change this line:

```
sortedList = listSort.OrderBy(x=> x.GetReflectedPropertyValue("Sort"),new MrFourCompare<string>()).ToList();
```

to

```
sortedList = listSort.OrderBy(x=> x.GetReflectedPropertyValue("Sort"),new MrFourCompare()).ToList();
```

because in implementation of `IComparer` you set it up to string.

**Edit:**

`IComparer` can not be `Dynamic`, so if you want to sort by Sort property of dynamic value you most cast sort property to exact type like `String` or `Int`.

```
sortedList = listSort.OrderBy(x=> (string)x.GetReflectedPropertyValue("Sort"),new MrFourCompare()).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank for your help. I tried it. However the error "cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly." still appears. Could you help me solve that error?

Comment: put your `IComparer` implementation here

Comment: This is my compare. 
    public class MrFourCompare : IComparer<String>
    {
        public int Compare(string x, string y)
        {
            return string.Compare(x, y);
        }
    }It's for test. I will modify it later. I need change value of property with string type to sort has result same SQL server. For ex:

Comment: It's for test. I will modify it later. I need change value of property with string type to sort has result same SQL server. For ex:
 + Result in Sql server:*1AaBbCc
 + Result in C#: *1ABCabc (it's not same sql)